# Arduino Nano incorrect analogReading values

Tags: arduino

I'm new in using Arduino, just recieved board from china today. Arduino Nano 3.0 clone (CH340). 
I installed drivers, everything worked at the first try. Tried to blink diode on it without problem.

Then I connected LM35Z (temperature chip) using built in voltage source. But I keep getting really weird values. They goes from 0 to 70 randomly very quickly.

raw values looks like this:

```
0
62
0
59
0
59
0
58
0
56
0
55
0
54
0
45
0
45
0
39
3
31
8
26
12
0
45
0
55
0
62
0
69
```

Any1 had similar experience or have any tips what am I doing wrong?

[image: Here is simplest circuit]
With code:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A5);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(200);        
}
```

Comment: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
6
8
10
14
17
20
23
25
29
32
35
36
41
42
46
49
52
55
57
60
60
62
62
62
61
60
60
57
57
56
56
55
55
53
53
52
49
46
42
38
35
31
28
24
22
18
15
11
8
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0 another output -_-

Answer (score 0):

Seems you code is ok. But try to use another pin, A0. Because A5 is sharing I2C interface and this may be the issue. Also:

- try to use decoupling capacitor 0.1 uF close to the sensor.
- you can do a simple check if the sensor is in good condition. Replace the sensor with voltage source with known output. Measure if output of adc function returns valid results.
- look at sensors output using osciliscope or multimeter. If it has voltage drops to zero or not.

I also suppose that you may be measuring voltage splashes at 50Hz (60 for US)  that are common for usb.

Comment: I have started with A0 going to A5. Every one do the same. Also tried to connect 1,5V battery - value goes to 345-346 stabil. Same with puttin it on the ground or 5v - 0 and 1023. Could You please write more about how to put 0,1 capacitor there?

Comment: But It seems that the voltage I read does cycles from lower to higher even if it's not connected to LM35Z.   
441
391
372
341
299
259
222
187
156
128
107
82
69
59
65
65
66
74
72
74
77
77
91
99
135
226
237
251
265
281
293
307
321
334
350
368
388
408
428
447 any ideas? :/

Comment: Look at page 14 of [the manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) , figures ##12,13

Comment: So I wired 1 uF capacitor from signal to GND, Now I'm getting stable value of 44 after few second at A05 pin. Thanks, but isn't it little bit small value? E: and when I try to heat it little bit (putting finger on it / light) value goes down. ??

Comment: Output voltage must rise if you heating the sensor. You should add capacitor to vcc, check if supply voltage of the sensor is 5V